How to improve stain coverage on pressure treated wood
This AC lattice cover is made from pressure treated wood. It has been in place for over a year. Water does not bead. Prior to doing a test stain, I cleaned it with a basic wood cleaner and an oxy bleach.
I tested two different makes of semi transparent oil stain. The results were not good.
The slat at the far left has two coats (the upper test is one coat of two different colors, because I was trying to get a gray that was less blue). The other slats are one coat of various versions of red because that's what they sent in the test kit. The picture was taken 3 days after the staining.
We were hoping to get a less grainy result or at least a more uniform coverage. Is there something I'm doing wrong or am I just expecting too much?


You use stain to show the grain/make the grain look good.  There are semi-solid stains or paint to hide the grain.

If you want to subdue the wood grain use paint,
if you want to accentuate it use stain.

Thanks. I'd previously used semi transparent stains on other woods with good results. I'll look for a semi solid stain.

The key issue here is that you are testing "semi transparent oil stain". Stain like that is meant to show the character of the wood, including the grain, through the stain coating.
If you want to hide the grain and get a more uniform look then aim for an solid color stain, particularly if you still want to stay with an oil based type finish. On the other hand get another type of product such as paint to cover your wood.
